# Restricting su command in a specific manner

Tags: sudo, user-permissions, su

I have a list of system users who have access to almost everything via sudo. Now I would like to restrict their sudo access for command su.

I would like to restrict *su* command for every user on system and allow every system user to be able to *su* to a specific user (in this case it is tomcat):

```
#user_name should be able to do *sudo su tomcat* but not *sudo su another_user*
user_name ALL=/bin/, !/bin/su, /bin/su tomcat
```

I tried different combination for this but unfortunately couldn't make it work.

Here is my complete /etc/sudoers file:

```
Defaults   !visiblepw
Defaults    always_set_home

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The /etc/sudoers.d/ has another file which contains the following:

```
meraj ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
siraj ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# Members of the group 'sysadmin' may gain root privileges
%sysadmin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

**Update 2:** When I do *sudo -l* from user meraj, I get this:

```
Matching Defaults entries for meraj on this host:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG
    LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE",
    env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User meraj may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (root) ALL, (root) !/bin/su
    (root) /bin/su tomcat
```

When I do sudo /bin/su tomcat or sudo /bin/su siraj then it asks me the password:

```
[sudo] password for meraj:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
username       ALL=(root)      /bin/su tomcat
```

works for me.  If it doesn't work for you, it may be because of **another** entry in the sudoers file, that permits a much wider range of commands, possibly unrestricted access to `/bin/su` - we'd need to see the whole of your `sudoers` file, unredacted, as well as detailed cut-and-paste of the failures, to be able to comment on that.

**Edit**: you have clarified that you are elsewhere granting the users permissions to do everything.  I found that explicitly removing sudo privileges to do su, with eg

```
username       ALL=(root)      ALL, !/bin/su
```

before giving them back just for tomcat with the line I quote at the beginning of my answer, worked.  If this doesn't work for you, could you show us the output of `sudo -l` for such a user, plus the outputs of `sudo /bin/su tomcat` and `sudo /bin/su userC` (where userC is a third user)?

Comment: @MadHatler Thanks for the response. I have updated the question with further details.

Comment: And I my answer.

Comment: Question has been updated with further information and output of the commands.

Comment: If that output is current, you haven't done what I suggested in this answer.  Also, what happens if you provide the password?

Comment: I added these two lines to end of sudoers file:
'meraj ALL=(root) ALL, !/bin/su
meraj ALL=(root) /bin/su tomcat'

And still same result. I pasted updated sudo -l out put as well in my origin question.

Comment: Updating these lines as: 

`meraj ALL=(root) ALL, !/bin/su
meraj ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/su tomcat`

solves my problem su command is now blocked for all users except for tomcat.

Comment: Can I ask you to clarify?  Are you saying then when you did as we advised you, it worked as you said you wanted it to?  If so, please accept this answer by clicking on the "tick" outline next to it, which will indicate to all that the problem is resolved.